# Async function behavior

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise

If I understand promises correctly shouldn't the following output be reversed.

```js
async function funcA() {
  console.log("executing funcA");
  await new Promise(function() {
    console.log("inside new promise")
  });
}

function funcB() {
  console.log("executing funcB");
}

funcA();
funcB();

//Outputs the following
"executing funcA"
"inside new promise"
"executing funcB"
```

How is this different from synchronously executing funcA

Comment: Add something _after_ your await.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `async`+`await` is merely a syntax sugar for chaining promises, so if you don't `await` anything you're still executing syncrhonously.

---

For example, take the function:

```
async function foo() {
    const users = await database.users.list();
    const pets = await database.pets.findFor(users);
    console.log("These are the application's users: ", users);
    console.log("And all their pets: ", pets);
}
```

It is compiled to basically this:

```
function foo() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        try {
            var users;
            var pets;
            database.users.list()
                .then(function (us) {
                    users = us;
                    return database.pets.findFor(users);
                })
                .then(function (ps) {
                    pets = ps;
                    console.log("These are the application's users: ", users);
                    console.log("And all their pets: ", pets);
                })
                .then(resolve, reject);
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        }
    });
}
```

And if you look at the documentation for the [`Promise` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), you'll see that the executor (the function you give it) is executed *immediately* (that is, synchronously).

---

So, back to your example, your "asynchronous" function will be implemented like this behind the scenes:

```
function funcA() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        try {
            console.log("executing funcA");
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        }
    });
}
```

So, the `console.log` will be executed synchronously.

Answer (score 1):

There is no await in the funcA pausing the execution, then funcA will be executed synchronously.

> An async function can contain an await expression that pauses the
>   execution of the async function and waits for the passed Promise's
>   resolution, and then resumes the async function's execution and
>   returns the resolved value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Description

Comment: I've updated the code snippet. Despite the await statement, it executes in a synchronous manner.

Comment: @AyushGoel Well, you missed the `Promise` constructor docs, the executor you give it is executed synchronously.